# Nvidia NVML Driver/library version mismatch: dkms, modules, drivers and modinfo versions

Tags: nvidia, kernel-module, dkms

I have the `Nvidia NVML Driver/library version mismatch` error, for which I recommend reading the following answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67105064/1782553
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71672261/1782553

However, after purging and re-installing the `nvidia` packages (necessary because of the issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436506/how-to-resolve-unmet-dependencies-error-when-upgrading-depends-nvidia-kernel-c)), I still get the error. A reboot resolved the issue but I'd like to understand why?
Also, I'm not sure I understand the meaning of the 4 following commands and the Nvidia version they display.

#### Before reboot

```
$ cat /sys/module/nvidia/version
515.65.01
```

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.65.01  Wed Jul 20 14:00:58 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

```
$ dkms status
nvidia, 515.65.07, 5.4.0-131-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
$ modinfo nvidia | grep ^version
version:        515.65.07
```

#### After reboot

```
$ cat /sys/module/nvidia/version
515.65.07
```

```
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.65.07  Thu Sep 22 00:22:12 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

```
$ dkms status
nvidia, 515.65.07, 5.4.0-131-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
$ modinfo nvidia | grep ^version
version:        515.65.07
```

---

I understand there's a difference between the loaded driver version and the driver version that will be loaded after next reboot, but I would have guessed that the `modinfo` version would match the `cat /proc/...` version, or that the `dkms` version would match the `cat /sys/...` version, but they don't…

Could someone make a brief summary of what each command is reading?